# how to achieve this in java ? requirement given below

Tags: java, list, dynamic, arraylist

I want to create a list of list

```
List<integer> nodes[10]=new ArrayList();
```

i want this, coz i will be iterating through it and reading data..and it will be dynamically created in runtime depending upon the size of inputs

Comment: So, you want an array of `ArrayList`s? `List<Integer> nodes[]=new ArrayList[10];`, but `List<List<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(10)` might be better...

Comment: : it would be really good if u could give me code to access each node and their element too @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an array of `List` seems a little weird to me, not that you can't do it, it just seems counter intuitive to me...

Instead, I'd create a `List` of `List`s, something like...

```
List<List<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(10);
```

You would then just need to populate them with actually values, this will depend on what you are doing, but something like...

```
nodes.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(10));
```

When you need to access a particular list/node, you would just access it like any normal `List`

```
List<Integer> listOfIntegers = nodes.get(0);
```

Take a look at the [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) tutorial and [`List` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [`ArrayList` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for more details.

Comment: what if i want to add elements to my array associated with my second node

Comment: The same way as you added the original list to the `nodes`...`listOfIntegers.add(1)` - check the [Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details...

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(size);
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{nodes.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(size));
 nodes.get(i).add(xyz);// i want to add elements to the list
 nodes=buildroot(nodes,intervals,i,x);//custom function to add elements to each list of list
}`

Answer (score 1):

An array of ArrayLists

```
List<Integer>[] nodes = new ArrayList[count];
```

An ArrayList of ArrayLists

```
List<List<Integer>> nodes = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(count);
```

Comment: it would be really good if u could give me code to access each node and their element too

Comment: @ajay23romu Try yourself. See the `get` method of `List`

Comment: i mean assigning values to list[i] and getting values.. it would be really great of u .. if u could give me just the syntaxes dude!! :P

Comment: @ajay23romu It's just like access any other array...`nodes[0] = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);`....